# UpdatePanel change my Table style

Tags: c#, asp.net, styles, updatepanel

i use nested usercontrol in my form
when page load i dont have any problem 
but when i checked my checkBox which is in an updatepanel my whole style ruined 
what is the problem ?

```
foreach (TableCell item in TC_mdfItems)
    {
        foreach (var item2 in item.Controls)
        {
            ((item2 as MdfItem).FindControl("CHKB_Select") as CheckBox).Checked = this.WCHK_RowSelector.Checked;
        }
    }
```

[image: i use the marked check box to select all usercontrol in that row]
[image: then it changes my style]

when I'm not using update panel its working but i want to do it with Ajax

Comment: are you using any jquery code at `$(document).ready`?

Comment: no just updatepanel for ajax

Comment: curious, cos you have been reading a lot of dave ward ( encosia ). are you doing anything on dom ready?

Comment: I have user control named MdfItem > an updatepanel include dropdown list , image , label , and checkbox , dropdown selected change make change in image ___ another usercontrol named MdfRow include number of MdfItem and a checkbox in an updatepanel checkedchange make all of mdfitem selected or deselect all in that row___ another user ocntrol is Mdf include MdfRows

Comment: in MdfRow when use Placeholder instead of updatepanel i dont have any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change my code this way

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_MdfRow" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div id="TableDIV" runat="server"></div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

when i add my usercontrol's table to div element it works fine .

thank you all